# Bind Alt Gr to right alt

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, lxde, dvorak

I am using [Programmer Dvorak keyboard layout](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/).  It binds the `right alt` key to `Alt Gr` (`ISO_Level3_Shift`).

How can I bind it back to `right alt`?

edit:
I am using Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) and LXDE.

In `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` it says:

```
// Programmer Dvorak, by Roland Kaufmann <rlndkfmn at gmail dot com>
// License: BSD, available at <http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/license.html>
//[SNIP]
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "dvp" {

    include "us(dvorak)"
    name[Group1] = "English (programmer Dvorak)";

    //[SNIP -- more keys here]

    // lower row, left side
    key <AB01> { [ apostrophe,      quotedbl,       dead_acute                  ] };
    key <AB07> { [ m,               M,              mu                          ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC" };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

Comment: did you download and install something [from that site](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/linux.html) or did you follow the directions to use the existing `us(dvp)` (programmer dvorak) layout from your system XKB?  what distribution and desktop are you using?  as near as i can tell the `dvp` variant included in XKB v2.22 (current, on my Arch) **does not** hardcode the RAlt-is-AltGr option (`level3:ralt_switch`), so all we need to do is figure out how you've set that option and stop setting it.  the `us(dvp)` layout is detailed in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`.

Comment: Commenting out `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` and saving the change to  `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` and restarting solves this for me.  Is there a better way for me to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Official Jessie packages provide the XKB database in `xkb-data` v2.12 ([source package `xkeyboard-config`](https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/xkeyboard-config)).  That hardcoded AltGr in `us(dvp)` was removed in [this commit](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/commit/symbols/us?id=50a7d5d6d5ef12289887336120c3c6cc6c0cb7ba), which looks like it made it into v2.17.  Currently the Debian Sid package is [v2.19](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/xkeyboard-config).

You've basically got two options to apply the fix yourself.

1. *Quick and dirty:* Edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` and comment out the line `include "level3(ralt_switch)"`.  Then reapply your keyboard layout (using `setxkbmap`, log out and back in, etc).  The change should take effect immediately.

   - **Advantage**: should take all of 20 seconds to apply, including checking the manpage of `setxkbmap`.
   - **Disadvantage**: if the Jessie `xkb-data` package is updated to a new version (but less than v2.17), you'll have to perform the edit again.
2. *Slow and clean:* Grab [Sid's `xkeyboard-config` package](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/xkeyboard-config) (any other Debian version v2.17 or newer would work too) and **create your own backport**.  Install any build dependencies, [build the binary packages](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingAPackage), and you'll have your very own Jessie version `xkb-data v2.19`.  Install this package (with `dpkg -i`, or add to a local apt repository, etc), reload your keymap, and you're in business.

   - **Advantage**: if Jessie updates the `xkb-data` package, your local package should be kept if the new Jessie package is older than v2.19.  Backporting software like this is safer than grabbing binary packages from other Debian distributions and installing them directly.
   - **Disadvantage**: other Jessie-era packages may have trouble with newer software.  This is fairly low-risk for `xkb-data`, but it's something to keep in mind.